# Playing mp3/wav sound causes exception

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

When playing audio using AVAudioPlayer, be it mp3 or wav, I'm getting an exception on all iPads and iPhone 4S and only iOS 9. This does not happen on any other devices.

The exception arises from

```
com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient (18): breakpoint 2.2
```

from

```
libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw:
```

and I'm catching it using a user breakpoint.
$arg1 does not contain anything

This is how I'm initializing AVAudioPlayer

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: type) else { return nil }
guard let url = URL(string: path) else { return nil }

try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, with: .mixWithOthers)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

return try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
```

I'm playing sound from an async global dispatch queue and the method playing the sound contains

```
self.sound?.prepareToPlay()
self.sound?.play()
```

Initially the file was a wav file, so I converted it to a mp3 file, which didn't help. I've also used a totally different sound, which produces the same exceptions.

The exception itself doesn't crash the simulator, although Rollbar reports SIGSEGV errors with such stracktrace:

`libAVFAudio.dylib in 0x27c1c000`

Audio class used:

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

class Audiotools {
    var sound: AVAudioPlayer?

    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audio")

    static var shared: Audiotools = {
        let manager = Audiotools()
        return manager
    }()

    init() {
        self.sound = configurePlayer(withFile: Files.sound.name, type: Files.sound.extension)
    }

    func configurePlayer(withFile file: String, type: String) -> AVAudioPlayer? {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: type) else { return nil }
        guard let url = URL(string: path) else { return nil }

        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, with: .mixWithOthers)
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        return try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    }

    func playSound() {
        self.dispatchQueue.async {
            self.sound?.prepareToPlay()
            self.sound?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Other Rollbar report:

```
SIGSEGV: Application terminated
libsystem_platform.dylib in _platform_memmove
AudioToolbox in Cached_DataSource::ReadFromHeaderCache(long long, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int*)
AudioToolbox in Cached_DataSource::ReadBytes(unsigned short, long long, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int*)
AudioToolbox in AudioFileObject::ReadBytes(unsigned char, long long, unsigned int*, void*)
AudioToolbox in AudioFileObject::ReadPacketDataVBR(unsigned char, unsigned int*, AudioStreamPacketDescription*, long long, unsigned int*, void*)
AudioToolbox in AudioFileReadPacketData
AVFAudio in AVAudioPlayerCpp::AQOutputCallbackCore(OpaqueAudioQueue*, AudioQueueBuffer*)
AVFAudio in AVAudioPlayerCpp::prepareToPlayQueue()
AVFAudio in AVAudioPlayerCpp::playQueue(AudioTimeStamp const*)
AVFAudio in AVAudioPlayerCpp::play()
AVFAudio in -[AVAudioPlayer play]
```

Has anyone else had this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out both the wav and mp3 audio files were corrupt. Converting to aiff solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback instead of AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient.

AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient : Use this category for background sounds such as rain, car engine noise, etc.
 Mixes with other music.

AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback : Use this category for music tracks.